# How do you change the size of the Docusign certificate of completion?

Tags: docusignapi

The current paper size is US Letter, and I would like to change the certificate of completion size to A4. Does anyone know of any configuration in Docusign or in the API to enable this?

[Certificate in docusign API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyChz.png)

For more context, the current API in GetDocumentOptions of EnvelopesApi shows certificate and I will like to change this certificate's size

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is something to handle this, but as far as i know that the certificate of completed documents comes in pdf format even if you use UI or API.

Use the getEnvelopeDocuments API to download the certificate of completion. Pass certificate as the documented.

GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/certificate

Comment: yea cool thanks! but is there any way to change the format of this pdf?